# sun snoop and multi file output

Tags: solaris-10, snoop

Is there any way snoop can cut output files every "x" minutes or every "y" Mbyts?
thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can't do this directly but you can capture to a file and then use something like `editcap` that comes with [wireshark](http://www.wireshark.org/) (available from [sunfreeware](http://sunfreeware.com/) )to split the file into multiple parts.

```
snoop -o pkts.cap
^C
editcap -i 300  pkts.cap cap_split
```

would split the original capture file into 5 minute blocks `cap_split*`.